# Capitalization of software terms--design pattern

Tags: proper-nouns

I'm editing a software blog, and the author is describing a design pattern called the "abstract factory pattern." He capitalizes the 'A' and the 'F' in some places and not in others.  The Wikipedia article is guilty of doing the same thing, and other software blogs are not proving to be reliable sources of grammatical correctness. I simply can't figure out if this is a proper noun or not.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Abstract Factory is the pattern's name, and it's used consistently as a proper noun in carefully edited sites such as [OODesign.com](http://www.oodesign.com/), as well as in the original *[Design Patterns](http://amzn.com/0201633612)* book by Gamma, Helm, Johnson, and Vlissides. (Take a look at the book's table of contents.)